# remove unwanted spaces between 2divs with css

Tags: html, css

Hi i has created this simple design:

```css
body{
  background: url("../imgs/bg_pattern.gif") scroll 0 0% repeat, url("../imgs/1.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0% / 100% 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

#panel{
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232325;
  float: right;
}

#audio{
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: red;
}
#term{
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 67%;
  background-color: green;
}
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.term{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: solid red;
}
.term:first-child{
  margin-left: 0;
}
.term:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="audio"></div>
    <div id="term">
      <div class="term"></div>
      <div class="term"></div>
      <div class="term"></div>
      <div class="term"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

But when I see the result, the `div`s which are in the term `div` have some space between each other. Setting the `padding` and `margin` to zero doesn't remove the space.

What should I do to remove the space to set the `div`s exactly near to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use in `term` container `display: flex`:

```css
body {
    background: url("../imgs/bg_pattern.gif") scroll 0 0% repeat, url("../imgs/1.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0% / 100% 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
#panel {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #232325;
    float: right;
}
#audio {
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    background-color: red;
}
#term {
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;/*Add display flex*/
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 67%;
    background-color: green;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    background-color: pink;
}
.term {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: solid red;
}
.term:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.term:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="audio"></div>
        <div id="term">
            <div class="term">asd</div>
            <div class="term">asd</div>
            <div class="term">asd</div>
            <div class="term">asd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**Reference**

[flex](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `Inline-block` have some default spaces ,

use Float to left better than `Inline-block` and use a clearfix class :

```
#term{
width: 100%;
height: 11%;
background-color: blue;
**overflow: hidden;**
}

.term{
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
width: 25%;
**float : left ;**
border-right: solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n0zxmgoy/

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier, any white space between inline blocks is retained in the layout, so one way
of getting rid of it is to make sure that the inline block elements have no intervening space
in the HTML mark-up.

Also, you need to set a reference height so that the height percentage values work as expected.
I did this by adding `height: 100%` to the `html` and `body` tags.

Also, make sure to add a height value to the `#header` element, which makes the arithmetic
a bit easier to deal with.

A subtle point involves the right border on the `.term` elements.  You can either use the
CSS `calc` value or `box-sizing: border-box`, you can try either.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; /* this may be needed... */
}

body{
  background: url("../imgs/bg_pattern.gif") scroll 0 0% repeat, url("../imgs/1.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0% / 100% 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

#panel{
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232325;
  float: right;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 22%;
}

#audio{
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: red;
}
#term{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 67%;
  background-color: green;
}
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.term{
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(25% - 2px);
  /* box-sizing: border-box; optional alternative */
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
.term:first-child{
  margin-left: 0;
}
.term:last-child{
  border-right: none;
  width: 25%; /* you need to consider this... */
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="audio"></div>
    <div id="term">
      <div class="term"></div><div class="term"></div><div class="term"></div><div class="term"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```